# React-Hook-Form: Unticked checkbox not being submitted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I am using `react-hook-form` and `chakra-ui` with useState Hooks in `Gatsby`.

I am trying to get the form to submit unticked (i.e. boolean false) checkboxes when submitted.

I have set the initial boolean to false from the state and I can see this in the developer tools, however when I submit the form it ignores all the `false` fields and will only submit if checked and state is `true`

```
<Checkbox
  name="CriminalRecord"
  value={CriminalRecord}
  ref={register}
  onClick={e => setCriminalRecord(e.target.checked)}
  width="100%"
  borderColor="purple.100"
  margin={3}
>
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have a checkbox group component? worth to just wrapped it with `Controller`.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Yes it has a group component, but not a controller. I will explore that. Thanks for a great library -  I am just exploring Little State Machine too now! :-)